# Unable to access Class members in Operator Overload

Tags: c++

Im new to c++, and I encountered this error where I cant access some class members I just defined in the constructor.

**Header**

```
.
. stuff before
.

class Rectangle : public Shape{
public:
    Rectangle(double width = 0, double length = 0);
    virtual double getArea() const;
    virtual double getVolume() const;
    Rectangle operator + (const Rectangle& rec);
    Rectangle operator - (const Rectangle& rec);
    double getWidth() const;
    double getLength() const;
private:
    double width_;
    double length_;

};

.
.  stuff after
.
```

**cpp**

```
.
. stuff before
.

Rectangle::Rectangle(double width, double length){
    width_ = width;
    length_ = length;
}

Rectangle::Rectangle operator + (const Rectangle& rec){
    Rectangle rect(width_+rec.width_, length_+rec.length);
    return rect;
}
Rectangle::Rectangle operator - (const Rectangle& rec){
    Rectangle rect(width_-rec.width_, length_-rec.length);
    return rect;
}

.
. stuff after
.
```

VSCode is basically telling me "identified width_ is undefined", and for rec.width_ "member 'Rectangle::width_' is inaccessible". What is occurring here?

Comment: The definition of the method should look like `Rectangle Rectangle::operator+(const Rectangle& rec)`, not `Rectangle::Rectangle operator+(const Rectangle& rec)`. Also `rec.length` should be `rec.length_`. When I fix these errors, your code [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/xThvn71z7). Maybe instead of trying to summarize what VS Code is "basically" telling you, you should construct a minimal reproducible example and include _exactly_ what errors you're getting.

Comment: A little reading on the useful [mre].

Comment: @NathanPierson thanks for the help! I will keep that in mind.